# Strange behaviour of Paragraph in FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument in XAML. If I insert a Paragraph like this:

```
<Paragraph>Any Text</Paragraph>
```

the Paragraph contains 1 Run with Text = "Any Text". (as expected)

If I insert a Paragraph like this:

```
<Paragraph>
   <Run Text="Any Text"/>
</Paragraph>
```

the Paragraph contains 3(!) Runs:
 
1. Run with Text = vbLf & "         " (some spaces)
 
2. Run with Text = "Any Text"
 
3. Run with Text = vbLf & "         " (some spaces)

What' s the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Humor me and try without the line breaks. <Paragraph><Run Text="Any Text"/></Paragraph>

Comment: frooook, you're right! Life can be so easy! Thanks